# How to make Grafana interpret my data as an Histogram?

Tags: sql, grafana

I'm using this dummy data just as an example. When applying this query on an Histogram panel I'm getting the wrong histogram. Why?

[image]

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN value BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN '0 - 9'
        WHEN value BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN '10 - 19'
        WHEN value BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20 - 29'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END AS `Bucket`,
    COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM
    (
        SELECT 5 AS value
        UNION ALL SELECT 12
        UNION ALL SELECT 18
        UNION ALL SELECT 8
        UNION ALL SELECT 25
        UNION ALL SELECT 30
        UNION ALL SELECT 12
        UNION ALL SELECT 22
        UNION ALL SELECT 7
        UNION ALL SELECT 15
    ) AS histogram_data
GROUP BY
    `Bucket`
ORDER BY
    MIN(value);
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: @jarlh, but I supplied an SQL query to produce the data. I'm just asking how to present it in Grafana as an histogram